# Identify lines that are out of order

Tags: text-processing, sort, verification

I have a process that generates output *mostly* in lexicographically sorted order according to a (timestamp) field, but occasionally the lines will be output in the wrong order:

```
2014-08-14 15:42:02.019220203 ok
2014-08-14 15:42:03.523164367 ok
2014-08-14 15:42:04.525655832 ok
2014-08-14 15:42:06.523324269 ok
2014-08-14 15:42:05.930966407 oops
2014-08-14 15:42:07.643347946 ok
2014-08-14 15:42:07.567283110 oops
```

How can I identify each location where the data are "unsorted"?

Expected output (or similar):

```
2014-08-14 15:42:05.930966407 oops
2014-08-14 15:42:07.567283110 oops
```

I need a solution that works as the data are generated (e.g. in a pipeline); it's less useful if it only operates on complete files. `sort --check` would be ideal but it only outputs the *first* point of disorder; I need a full listing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk 'NR>1 && $0"" < last; {last=$0}'
```

Prints the lines that sort before the preceding line. The `$0""` is to force lexical comparison (on the output of `seq 10` it would spot `10` as sorting before `9`).

Answer (score 1):

I think that shell string comparisons *should* respect lexicographical order (according to the current locale, of course) - so perhaps you could do something like

```
#!/bin/bash

lastline=""
while IFS= read -r line; do 
  [[ "$line" < "$last" ]] && printf '%s\n' "$line"
  last="$line"
done < <(your process)
```

Comment: On the output of `seq 1000000`, I find it's about 50 times as slow as the `gawk` equivalent (12x for `ksh93`, 20x for `zsh` and `mksh`, and `mawk` is twice as fast as `gawk`). IMO at least, using `while read` loops to process text is bad practice. At least here, you didn't fall into the usual pitfalls though.